# Creating a drop down list from another table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am trying to add a relational field drop down select to the existing table. My current Schema

```
create_table "hardwares", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "serialnumber"
  t.string "modelnumber"
  t.string "modeltype"
  t.string "location"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "poc_id"
  t.index ["poc_id"], name: "index_hardwares_on_poc_id"
end

create_table "pocs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "address"
  t.string "facility"
  t.string "phone"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The index field in the hardwares table was created when I ran the migration.

```
rails g migration addPocReferencesToHardwares poc:references
```

which generated the migration file below as well as the index in the schema

```
class AddPocReferencesToHardwares < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :hardwares, :poc, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

After setting up the relationship, I would like to be able to select a POC for the hardware by name as a drop down of all available POC's.

I added this to the Hardware form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label "POC" %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:poc_id, Poc.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a POC', :selected => @poc.poc_id }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
</div>
```

The error I get is " undefined method `poc_id' for nil:NilClass". How do I allow a drop down selection for adding a POC to the hardware?

Comment: Your problem is that `@poc` is nil (as stated in your error message). Since you don't show anything about where or how you set `@poc`, it's pretty much impossible to help you without just wild guessing.

Comment: Ok, haha, should have been @hardware. Thanks jvillian. My brain was a little bit stuck this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was the fact that I had set the relationship as POC belongs to Hardware, thus in the Form field it needed to be:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label "POC" %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:poc_id, Poc.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select a POC', :selected => @hardware.poc_id }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
</div>
```